# Модуль keyboard

Tags: python, консоль, клавиатура, библиотеки, python-keyboard

При импорте модуля keyboard ,при запуске программы консоль открывается и сразу закрывается, не зависимо от того используется ли модуль в программе или нет, в PyChurm все работает, данный модуль вообще умеет работать в консольных приложениях? что я делаю не так?

Comment: Приложите код. Без него могу вам лишь ответить - у вас ошибка в коде, вон в той строке, чуть ниже той где всё верно написано.

Comment: @Amgarak это вообще не имеет значение, такое происходит даже если модуль никак не используется, просто import keyboard и в любом случае ошибка, без модуля код работает прекрасно

Comment: Кода ошибки я тоже не вижу. Предлагаете подрубить экстрасенсорные способности?

Comment: Делаете файл из одной строки `import keyboard` - запустился без ошибок? Тогда постепенно переносите туда все свои импорты, все еще без ошибок? Ну тогда вписываете тоже постепенно код, может сами поймете, какая строка вызывает проблемы. Некоторые интерактивные модули (readline, keyboard) при запуске из-под PyCharm ведут себя иначе, чем "без него".

Comment: @Amgarak если запускать через idle то modulenotfound, опечаток нет, модуль я устанавливал через терминал раз 50, pip пишет то что он установлен

Comment: @AlexTitov просто строка import keyboard вызывает ошибку modulenotfound, хотя так то он установлен , последней версии, проверял несколько раз

Comment: Возможно, в PyCharm запускается "другой" python :)  Если на компе устанвлена одна версия, то, вероятно, в PyCharm проект в `virtual environment`. Модуль `keyboard` из-под PyCharm ставили, или "без него"?

Comment: Да, скажите на всякий случай, у Вас windows, или linux?